# .then promise with sendMessage not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, web-worker

I have the following code inside a webworker,

```
onmessage = function(e)
{
    var data;
    var message = e.data;
    sendTimeSeries = false;
    var semicolon = message.split(";");
    for (var i=0; i<semicolon.length;i++)
    {
        var colon= semicolon[i].split(":");
        for(var j=0; j<colon.length; j++)
        {
            if(colon[j] == "Insert TimeSeries")
            {
                stringTimeSeriesTableData = ""
                data = colon[j+1].split(" ");
                prevLetter = data[0];
                getAllRecords(prevLetter).then(addTimeSeries).then(getAllTimeSeries).then(sendMessage); //use of promises
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The methods `getAllRecords`, `addTimeSeries` and `getAllTimeSeries` are being called in the correct order (won't go into the next method until the previous one has finished executing. However, the `sendMessage` webworker method is being called before finishing the `getAllTimeSeries` method.

getAllRecords():

```
function getAllRecords(letter)
{
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var trans = db.transaction(["ObservableStates"],"readonly").objectStore("ObservableStates").index('letterIndex');

    var request = trans.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(letter));

    request.onsuccess = function(event)
    {
        cursor = event.target.result;
        if(cursor)
        {
            count = count + 1;
            console.log(cursor.value);
            addRecordToHistory(cursor.value);
            deleteObservableStates(cursor.primaryKey);
            while(cursor.continue())
            {
            }
        }
        if(cursor==null)
        {
            console.log('ready from count');
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    }

    request.onerror = function(event)
    {
        console.log('ERROR LOADING DATA FROM TABLE');
    }
    return deferred.promise();

}
```

addTimeSeries

```
function addTimeSeries()
{
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    timeSeries = {
        l:prevLetter, t:count
    }
    request = db.transaction(['TimeSeries'], "readwrite").objectStore('TimeSeries').add(timeSeries);

    request.onerror = function(event)
    {
        console.log("Unable to add timeSeries to table TimeSeries");
    }
    request.onsuccess = function(event)
    {
        console.log("TimeSeries State Added");
        deferred.resolve();
    }

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

getAllTimeSeries()

```
function getAllTimeSeries()
{
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    req = db.transaction(['TimeSeries'], "readonly").objectStore('TimeSeries').openCursor();

    req.onerror = function(event)
    {
        console.log("Unable to stringify all records");
    }

    req.onsuccess = function(event)
    {
        cursor=event.target.result;
        if(cursor)
        {
            stringTimeSeriesTableData += cursor.value.l + "," + cursor.value.t + ";";
            while(cursor.continue())
            {
            }
        }
        if(cursor==null)
        {
            console.log(stringTimeSeriesTableData);
            sendTimeSeries = true;
            deferred.resolve();
            console.log('got all time series');
        }
    }
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Is there something I'm missing here? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "finishes"? What output do you get that is in unexpected order?

Comment: Maybe you want to place the `deferred.resolve()` after the `console.log('got all time series');` line?

Comment: What is this weird `if (cursor) { while(cursor.continue()) } else { deferred.resolve() }` thing? Are you expecting `onsuccess` to be called multiple times per request?

Comment: Your last two functions [lack the `var` keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488/1048572) for the variables `timeSeries`, `request`, `req`, and `cursor`, and have `stringTimeSeriesTableData` and `sendTimeSeries` nowhere declared. That's probably the issue, especially when your function is called multiple times concurrently.